# How to connect to web socket in Vue 3 or Nuxt 3 and display a message on receiving the message?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket, nuxt.js, subscription

I want to build a web application using Vue 3 or Nuxt 3 where I want to subscribe to a Web Socket using the URL, ClientID and Client Secret and on receiving a message within the subscription I want to display an alert message in the web application.

Currently, I am able to subscribe and get the respective alerts in the PostMan collection but I want to build my own web application rather than Postman. I am unable to get the message in my WebSocket even though it shows connected to Web Socket.

How to connect to Web Socket and display the alert message in Web Application:

```
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
const config = useRuntimeConfig();
const socketUrl = config.public.WS_URL;
const clientId = config.public.WS_CLIENT_ID;
const clientSecret = config.public.WS_CLIENT_SECRET;
const webSocket = ref(null);
const isConnected = ref(false);

export const connectWebSocket = () => {

    const completeSocketURL = socketUrl + "&Authorization=Bearer ";

    console.log(completeSocketURL);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("keycloakToken"))

    const socket = new WebSocket(completeSocketURL + localStorage.getItem("keycloakToken"));

    socket.onopen = function (event) {
        isConnected.value = true;
        console.log("Connection Opened : " + JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
    };

    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
        console.log("WS Received Message : " + JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
    };

    socket.onerror = function (event) {
        console.error("WS Error Received : " + JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
    };

    socket.onclose = function (event) {
        isConnected.value = false;
        console.log("WS Disconnected : " + JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
    };

    webSocket.value = socket;
};
```

Comment: Just to rule out any errors, add an [error handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/error_event) to your socket and see if any errors are getting raised. Also it might help to inspect the WebSocket traffic in [dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#frames). Are you expecting a response back after the "authMessage"?

Comment: @CalvinFurano I have modified the code in question and added the error handler. I do not get any error. It says connected and immediately says disconnected. I am unable to keep the connection open for some reason. Can you please let me know what am I missing here?

Comment: Sorry @batman-2008, it's hard to diagnose without knowing more about the WebSocket server you're connecting to. Off the top of my head, this could be a CORS issue. It could also be a TLS issue. Does your WebSocket URL start with `ws://` or `wss://` ?

Comment: @CalvinFurano Thanks a lot for the response. I can understand. My WebSocket has the `wss://`, here is the domain which follows the same format as my original: `wss://example.domain.net/queries/alert/events?stream=true`. I am also trying to append `token` to it to authenticate and subscribe to web socket. I have also updated my code with the changes that I have been trying recently.